# UnexpectedValueException after loading plugin

Tags: plugin-development, twigextension

I'm attempting my first Craft plugin and trying to update https://github.com/matthewattanasio/Craft-Url-Decoder-Twig-Extension for Craft 3 and followed the instructions in the [docs for loading plugins](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/plugin-guide.html#loading-your-plugin-into-a-craft-project) which seemed to work in that the plugin appeared in the control panel, but I also got the following error:

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>     Package cakephp/core's source key should be specified as {"type": ..., "url": ..., "reference": ...},
>     {"type":"git","url":"https://github.com/cakephp/core.git","reference":null} given.

and now when I try to run any more composer commands I get the same error so I'm unable to do

```
composer remove package/name
composer require package/name
```

because I've made some changes to file names and need to update it.

The plugin is still showing in the CP but showing old information and when I try to install it, I get a server error.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to replace all references to `"reference":null` with  `"reference":""` in `/craft/vendor/composer/installed.json`.